# In what contexts was самомобилизация used in older (Soviet) times?

Tags: словоупотребление

This term, самомобилизация, recently surfaced in the [news](https://lenta.ru/news/2022/09/16/nizhh/) to refer to the forming of (more) volunteer battalions. However, the term was apparently in use [before](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), having been included in a dictionary of neologisms from the 1960s (Новые слова и значения. Словарь-справочник по материалам прессы и литературы 60-х годов / Под редакцией Н. З. Котеловой и Ю. С. Сорокина. — М. : Советская энциклопедия, 1971.) Since I cannot easily get my hands on that reference/dictionary, I wonder if you'd know in what contexts самомобилизация was used in older times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the meanings roughly corresponds to English "self-motivation.” It’s about mustering one's will and staying focused in the pursuit of one's goals. Here are couple of quotes to give you an idea:

> Наиболее значимыми факторами, влияющими на ее формирование, являются
> мотивация, самомобилизация человека на плодотворный труд.

or

> Теперь я знаю, что именно эта самая самомобилизация и дает силы, и
> возникает она именно тогда, когда кажется, что не знаешь, с чего
> начать, как бы из пустоты.

In a more general sense, "самомобилизация" is about rallying volunteer power for some social, communal event. Within the context of the USSR, it most likely refers to a state-imposed event (as in "самомобилизация пролетариата", "самомобилизация работников культуры" etc.):

[image]

Obviously, in this meaning, it's closer to the notorious modern-day recurrence of this word. I use the term *recurrence*, and not *reinterpretation* because in fact a military usage of "самомобилизация" also existed. Here's [a quote](http://militera.lib.ru/memo/russian/rudniy_va3/01.html):

> Я стоял посреди комнаты второго отдела Пубалта и, ожидая решения своей
> судьбы, строил запасные планы самомобилизации на случай, если полковой
> комиссар Кирилл Петрович Добролюбов сейчас мне в этом откажет.